# ajax call to php not working properly

Tags: php, html, ajax

i'm making an ajax call to a php function... i'm trying to display the server time on the time input field using a php script... i was following a tutorial i found online word per word but for some reason i keep receiving the actual text from the php file in time input field... can someone please tell me why this is happening?

here's my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Server Time Example</title>
</head>
<body>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
    //Browser Support Code
    function ajaxFunction() {
        var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

        try {
            // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
            ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch (e) {
            // Internet Explorer Browsers
            try {
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                try {
                    ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e) {
                    // Something went wrong
                    alert("Your browser broke!");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
        ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4) {
                document.myForm.time.value = ajaxRequest.responseText;
            }
        }
        ajaxRequest.open("GET", "serverTime.php", true);
        ajaxRequest.send(null);
    }

//-->
</script>

<form name='myForm'>
Name: <input type='text' onChange="ajaxFunction();" name='username' /> <br />
Time: <input type='text' name='time' />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the PHP:

```
<?php
  echo date("H:i:s");

?>
```

Comment: Why aren't you using an external ajax library like j

Comment: @David MZ - While jQuery is lovely, it isn't a requirement to use it in every web application.  There's nothing wrong with rolling your own.

Comment: @David MZ: There's no problem here with the self-dev AJAX approach. It's good for *some* folks to learn the nuts and bolts. Yes, libs make it easier, but for the curious, they also obscure. Live and let dev. :)

Comment: Agh! Ek0nomik posted 13 secs before me. Sorry, I wasn't piling on. :)

Comment: High fives for everyone! Down with the tyranny of jQuery! Long live Roll-Your-Own! :P

Comment: @Chris: :D  Well, you're not gonna get many knocks on jQuery from me. It's an *amazing* tool. But it's just a tool. Use as needed. :)

Comment: Make a page test.php w/ <?php phpinfo(); ?> then navigate to the page. If it displays the text, you need to install PHP support into your webserver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to make the assumption you are using Apache as your web server.  You should ensure you have something similar to the following in your configuration:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

It looks like your files are being served as plain text instead of being handed off to PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following:

1. **The php code (`echo date("H:i:s");`) should be in a separate file from the ajax/html code** (technically there are ways to get around this, but they make everything much more complicated)
2. The php file should have the `.php` extension
3. Your server should be configured to treat the `.php` file extension as php code (see Ek0nomik's answer)
4. The php code should have `<?php` and `?>` tags around it
5. Your server should have php installed

If all this fails, go to the php file directly in your browser and see what comes up.

Comment: My php file is separate from my html file and in the same directory. Also it has the .php extension. 
When you say that my server should be configured to treat the .php file extension, what do you mean exactly? I installed apache 2.2.20 on to my machine and I'm running windows xp sp2

Comment: I figured it out... Thanks for all your help... turns out that I forgot to set the short_tags in the php.ini file to on thats why it wasnt reading my php script properly :P

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to play [Carnac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnac_the_Magnificent) and say it's because you don't have `<?PHP` at the beginning of your file and `?>` at the end of your file.

Comment: Or the web server isn't setup correctly to handle files with the .php extension (i.e. they are just being served as plain text).

Comment: @Ek0nomik: Yessir, I think that is the problem after seeing that the PHP code is inserted at the bottom of his post.

Comment: @Ek0nomik: You should post that as an answer.

Comment: I just did.  Are there any other troubles in the world we should tackle together?  World hunger, poverty?

Comment: the php file is separate and in the same directory as my html file and it has the php tags like that at the beginning and end

Comment: Yep. See Ek0nomik's answer above about your configuration file. Basically, your apache server doesn't know that it should be processing php files before it sends them out.

Comment: @theNewbProgrammer: Also, are you sure PHP has been installed on the server?

Comment: I figured it out... Thanks for all your help... turns out that I forgot to set the short_tags in the php.ini file to on thats why it wasnt reading my php script properly :P

Comment: Hmmm. You didn't use short tags in the example above, so that shouldn't have mattered. BTW, consider **not** using short tags. See: http://www.bin-co.com/php/articles/using_php_short_tags.php . Regardless, glad you got it working.